# I create new provision profile want to update it in xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios

I update my provision profile with new device id in apple account. I downloaded new provision profile but in new built my new provision profile was not updated. Can any one give some process by which I can update my provision profile.

Comment: Was your new profile visible in XCode Organizer? And It allowed you to select that profile before creating the build?

Comment: I can see it in XCode Organizer but I am seeing it before creating the build.

Comment: In Organizer you can also see the creation date of that Profile. Can you see the one which you created today?

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is you have not added the device. Can you re-confirm if you have added the device?

Comment: Try this small thing, Just clean the project before you build the app. And make sure you've selected Provisioning profile in both Project and Target.

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'testvijay' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.future.vijaytest' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.future.vijaytest'
warning: iOS deployment targets lower than 4.3 are not supported (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7").

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25279/discussion-between-rushi-and-vijay-verma)

Comment: It is solved ! Cheers ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the Provisioning profile in both Target as well as Project section. Follow the below mention steps :

1. You logged in to Apple Developer "Member Center"
2. You added the UDID of device
3. You went to provisioning profile section and edited your profile. Selected a check mark next to it
4. You refereshed your page and downloaded the new profile
5. Now you selected this new profile in both Project and Target.

It's important to select provisioning profile in both Project and Target.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can open `Xcode Organizer->Provisioning profiles` in Devices Tab Section and delete all the profile and refresh it, and new profiles will appear, don't forget to see if they have `status valid profiles`. Make sure you clean the keychain also for old profile requests. you could follow this tutorial to [step by step provisioning profile](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

First delete old profile from your xCode. Now double click on the new profile and that profile will updated in the xCode

All the best !!!